# Twilio how to detect hold music from participant

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I wrote a python app that create conference call, when adding a company to the call there is an hold music from the company.
I want to detect when someone from the company picks up the phone.
so I thought detecting when the hold music stops or something?
Is there any methods in twilio documents that can help me?
Thank you !

Tried to find in Twilio's documentation and googled about it, found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to used the [Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) and check whether the `AnsweredBy` property is `human`?